# Maintain line numbers in uglifyJS (or alternative)

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I need to concatenate/minify some javascript code while maintaining the line numbers. I don't think I can use a source map.

Situation: I have a production site that reports errors the stacktrace back to my server when they appear for end-users, and it is very difficult to debug certain errors, without knowing the line numbers.

I seem to remember an option in uglifyJS2, but it looks like it might have gone by the wayside (probably because source maps are so useful).

Any minifier will do. If there are other reasonable options that will work for my situation, I'm open to suggestions.

Edit: I know I can just concatenate the files, but I would like to minify/obfuscate them.

Comment: If you can get a source map you can get the location for the error or is the problem you don't know how to get the source map for your uglified/concatenated code?

Comment: I know I can use a source map in conjunction with the developer tools, if I am the one who got the error. I am not the one who got the error. It is an end-user in production (and I don't know how they got the error). I don't want the source map available to the production site, because that defeats the purpose of obfuscating the files. All I get is the real backtrace of the error in production.

Comment: You don't need the developer tools from the browser, you can use other alternatives like https://github.com/mozilla/source-map